# limit of a random matrix, does it have full rank with probability 1?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, matrix-rank, random-matrices

Let $X_1, X_2, ... i.i.d$ and $Y_1, Y_2, ... i.i.d$ be the random variables s.t
$E(X)=E(Y)=0$ and $Var((X,Y)^T)$ (which is 2 by 2 matrix) is positive definite. (not semi)

Let $A_n$ a $n \times 2$ random matrix

$\begin{bmatrix}
    X_1 & Y_1\\
    X_2 & Y_2\\
... &...\\
X_n & Y_n
  \end{bmatrix}$
.

does $P(rank ( A_n)=2) $ goes to $1$ as $n$ goes to the infinity?

I think the probability increases as n increases, but couldn't prove or disprove whether is goes to 1.

I also tried to use the law of large number ot $(A_n^TA_n)/n$ as it converges to  $Var((X,Y)^T)$ under good conditions, but I don't know the relationship of matrix convergence and the rank of matrix.

Comment: Why answer your questions since you do not read the answers ?          https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709770/limit-of-the-probability-of-a-random-matrix-has-full-rank/2713404#2713404